# What does default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default mean?

Tags: symlink, nginx

I am looking at `nginx/sites-enabled` folder

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Mar 31 11:52 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

What does default-? denote?

Comment: You seem to understand that it's a symbolic link. What part is it that is unclear?

Comment: @Kusalananda It means that it will look all the time by default? what if new file is added? will that change something?

Comment: nginx use the symbolic link to activate (when link is set) or desactivate (when link is deleted) site defined in `../sites-available`